# Can't assign method to onPressed from Dao delete method

Tags: flutter, future, flutter-moor

Error:

```
The argument type 'void Function()' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function(BuildContext)?'.
```

Code

```
  return Slidable(
    endActionPane: ActionPane(
      motion: ScrollMotion(),
      children: <Widget>[
        SlidableAction(
          label: 'Delete',
          foregroundColor: Colors.white,
          backgroundColor: Colors.red,
          icon: Icons.delete,
          onPressed: () => database.deleteGoal(itemGoal),
        ),
      ],

    ),
```

function form moore_database.dart

```
  Future deleteGoal(Goal goal) => delete(goals).delete(goal);
```

How should I approach this problem I have read that I should change method for `VoidCallback`, but what is correct solution with defining in good manner database methods.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of,

```
onPressed: () => database.deleteGoal(itemGoal),
```

Put the `context`.

```
onPressed: (context) => database.deleteGoal(itemGoal),
```